# Prerender does not return a page response

Tags: prerender

Long story short:

1. Server OS got updated, which broke my virtualenv's. Before this everything worked just fine.
2. Reinstalled the environment.
3. Tried to fire up Prerender.io middleware with the following env variables (usually run by supervisor, now tried manually):

`

```
export PORT=35292
export PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL='http://localhost:35292/'
export PHANTOMJS_PORT=35294
export PHANTOM_CLUSTER_NUM_WORKERS=5
export PHANTOM_WORKER_ITERATIONS=10
export CACHE_ROOT_DIR="/home/users/jz/snapshot-env/prerender/filecache/"
export CACHE_LIVE_TIME=7200
PHANTOM_CLUSTER_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT=800
```

`

4. Set up the demo server `demoserver.js`:

`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var prerender = require('./lib');

var server = prerender({
    workers: process.env.PRERENDER_NUM_WORKERS,
    iterations: process.env.PRERENDER_NUM_ITERATIONS
});


//server.use(prerender.sendPrerenderHeader());
// server.use(prerender.basicAuth());
// server.use(prerender.whitelist());
server.use(prerender.blacklist());
// server.use(prerender.logger());
server.use(prerender.removeScriptTags());
server.use(prerender.httpHeaders());
// server.use(prerender.inMemoryHtmlCache());
// server.use(prerender.s3HtmlCache());

server.start();
```

`

5. Server starts:

`

```
$ node demoserver.js 
2016-05-24T01:41:35.814Z starting worker thread #0
2016-05-24T01:41:35.832Z starting worker thread #1
2016-05-24T01:41:35.839Z starting worker thread #2
2016-05-24T01:41:35.842Z starting worker thread #3
2016-05-24T01:41:35.844Z starting worker thread #4
2016-05-24T01:41:36.120Z starting phantom...
2016-05-24T01:41:36.132Z Server running on port 35292
2016-05-24T01:41:36.135Z starting phantom...
2016-05-24T01:41:36.146Z starting phantom...
2016-05-24T01:41:36.152Z Server running on port 35292
2016-05-24T01:41:36.153Z starting phantom...
2016-05-24T01:41:36.160Z Server running on port 35292
2016-05-24T01:41:36.170Z Server running on port 35292
2016-05-24T01:41:36.176Z starting phantom...
2016-05-24T01:41:36.190Z Server running on port 35292
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
```

`

6. Try to access the server locally:

`$ lynx http://localhost:35292/http://google.com`

I see it tries to fetch the page, but no response:
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.

On the server log I see it has received the request:

`2016-05-24T01:53:42.449Z getting http://google.com/`

After that no entries and no action. I see prerender has indeed spawned several phantomjs processes, but for some reason nothing happens.

Any ideas how to debug this further to see why phantomjs is not processing or returning the request?

Edit: npm install output [here](https://gist.github.com/amergin/abe2c31e385e03521cc8c5792c90c41b) - don't see anything fishy.

```
(snapshot-env)jz@lakka:~/snapshot-env/prerender$ uname -a
Linux lakka 3.14.66-grbfs-kapsi #1 SMP Sat Apr 16 10:30:24 EEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux


(snapshot-env)jz@lakka:~/snapshot-env/prerender$ cat /etc/*release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Node version:

```
jz@lakka:~$ cd snapshot-env;source bin/activate
(snapshot-env)jz@lakka:~/snapshot-env$ node -v
v6.2.0
```

Comment: That's weird. Were there any errors when you ran `npm install`? What system are you on? What version of node are you using?

Comment: @Prerender.io: see my edit.

Comment: @Prerender.io: any ideas how to solve this thing? My site basically vanished from Google because of this, and its super annoying since there's not even an error message that would help me solve it.

Comment: I don't see any issues. Are you running your own Prerender server or using our hosted service? Our hosted service doesn't have these issues so your local prerender server not running should not cause you to vanish from Google. Can you email me at todd@prerender.io with your account info and URL of your website so we can look into making sure it's working on our hosted service?

Comment: I'm running my own Prerender server. It's because while my host allows me to set up custom rules via `.htaccess`, they do not allow to set the necessary header to show Prerender token and hence I cannot use your service directly. This all is very puzzling because I had my own Prerender service working fully before the upgrade.

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you using?

Comment: @Prerender.io: My Node version is `v6.2.0`. Is there a particular version that I should try out?

Comment: Yeah try 4.2.6 if you can

Comment: @Prerender.io: same problem with version `v4.2.6`: no response although I see the request coming through. Installed the node version using `nodeenv --node=4.2.6`.

Comment: Can we get on a screenshare? Something weird is going on there and it's not easy to debug this through StackOverflow comments :) Mind emailing me at todd@prerender.io?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey I have this problem before, I fixed by these commands

### 1. Downgrade to node 4.x

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

### 2. Fix the issue: `Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag`

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

That's it. 
Hopefully, it can help you.

I reinstall the service and I wrote a blog showing the flows

check it out http://ccaloha.cc/blog/2016/06/22/how-to-install-preloader-dot-io-service-in-ubuntu-14-dot-04/

Comment: Excellent! It was all about the locales. In hindsight, the console output *did* give a clue about the culprit after all, albeit as a warning. Never would've thought the improper language settings would inhibit the binary from being run.

Comment: This literally saved my life. Thanks a ton.